# How to apply Shortcut keys in kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I need a shortcut keys to access my kendo grid so my main issue is explained below
[image]

Comment: Have you tried exploring the accesskey  attribute while designing the UI/HTML

Comment: Hope this URL helps, http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/keyboard-navigation

Comment: No Lucky this is not giving the appropriate result alredy tried but any way thanks for the effort